# Python Button Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, botón

Tengo este código, el cual la idea es cambiar los atributos de varios botones en Tkinter.

```
    for i in range (0, 8):
        c = (i + 1)
        btn1 = "boton"+str(b)+str(c)
        if locals()["columna_"+str(b)][i] == "1":
            #toggle3g(btn1, 11, 64)
            btn = locals()[btn1]
            btn.config(relief="sunken",bg="green1")
            print(btn, "ON!!!")
        else:
            #toggle3goff(btn1, 11, 64)
            btn = locals()[btn1]
            btn.config(relief="sunken",bg="green1")
            print(btn, "OFF!!!")
```

Me devuelve:

> KeyError: 'boton11'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomiendo usar listas en lugar de crear variables con `locals()` o `globals()`.

Aquí hay un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def boton_accion(row, column):
    estados[row][column] = not estados[row][column]
    print("boton[{}][{}]".format(row, column))
    if estados[row][column]:
        botonos[row][column].config(relief="sunken")
        print("ON!!!")
    else:
        botonos[row][column].config(relief="raised")
        print("OFF!!!")


ancho = 10
altura = 8

# Inicializamos listas bidimensionales para botones y sus estados
botons = [[None] * ancho for i in range(altura)]
estados = [[False] * ancho for i in range(altura)]

# Completa la lista de botones
for i in range(altura):
    for j in range(ancho):
        boton = tk.Button(root, text=str(i)+str(j), command=lambda row=i, column=j: boton_accion(row, column))
        boton.grid(row=i, column=j)
        botonos[i][j] = boton

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Exelente aporte!!! Ya me pongo con esta práctica!

Comment: @MatiasScaramuzzino No olvides marcar la pregunta como aceptada si te ha resuelto el problema.